# Can't get 2 different Substrings from a String C#

Tags: c#, string, substring

I have a task. 
I should extract two substrings from a string.
The lenght of the String will be different each time, so the method should be generic.

Suppose I have the following String:

```
/*Description:\r\n*RANGE:\r\n*HIGH\r\n*LOW\r\n*/
```

I need to get the `substring1= HIGH` and `substring2= LOW`.
The `substring1` and `substring2` will be all the time between `\r\n`, but they values will be different.

I would be very grateful if anybody helps me. It can be a pseudocode, anything.

Thanks in advance.

UPDATE1: I'm searching first for "RANGE:\r\n*" and get the index of the character * and the index og character "H". But next don't know how to get the whole substring.

Comment: So what have you tried so far? Can you please show the code of your current attempt?

Comment: split string by `\r\n` and then iterate through resulting array

Comment: Are you looking for the last two lines (excluding the comment end)?

Comment: @Richard you are right. I have couple of such comments and I need to take two values that forward the string "RANGE:"

Comment: @Richard                                                                                             
/* Description:
 * RANGE: 
 * HIGH
 * LOW                                                                                                            */

Comment: You may not be aware that the C# string class has a `Split()` method.  You should check into that.

Comment: If you know in advance which substrings you're looking for, there's no need to "extract" them.  You already have them.  What you seem to want is to find out if the substring in question is present.  I'm not quite sure what you're asking.

Comment: @Cyberherbalist I don't know what values will follow the substring "RANGE:" each time

Comment: Use StringReader to read lines of input.

Answer (score 0):

If the pattern you've provided is similar to what you'd expect all the time, a stupid simple approach would be:

```
public static string[] GetParts(string input)
{
    string[] parts= input.Split("\r\n", StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    return parts.TakeLast(2).Select(item=>item.Replace("*", string.Empty)).ToArray();
}
```

**Note**: This is not a production quality code.